# Lower bound an integral

Tags: calculus

Consider a decreasing, convex, positive function $f:[1,\infty)\to(0,1]$ with $f(1)=1, \lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 0$ and its derivative satisfies $f'(1)=-1, \lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f'(x) = 0$.

I am interested in finding out a "tight" lower bound for the following integral: $$ \int_{1}^{\infty} \left( (f'(x))^2 e^{-f(x)} -\frac{e^{-x}}{f'(x)} \right) dx $$

This is always positive, and I know that one trivial lower bound is $1/e$, because the first term is always positive, and the second term is $$ \int_{1}^{\infty} -\frac{e^{-x}}{f'(x)} dx \ge \int_{1}^{\infty} e^{-x} dx = \frac{1}{e} $$

I believe (through some numerical computations) that the integral is always $\ge 1$, and my conjecture is that it's also $\ge 2$, for which I know that it is attained by $f(x)=1/x$. Any ideas for proving that $2$ is indeed a lower bound, or finding a "tight" lower bound?